# could "further" refer to "later" or "afterwards/then" regarding a context?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Next, the bricks are dried in an oven for 24-48 hours, before baking them in a kiln, first at moderate temperature of 200-980C followed by extremely high temperature of 870-1300C.They are ***further*** cooled for 48-72 hours in the cooling chamber, and are later packed and loaded in trucks, thus, preparing them for delivery to different places.

Does "further" in the context above mean ***later or afterwards***? Could this word mean later or afterwards at all, regard a context?

Comment: I think this is not an idiomatic use of the word **further**, given the fact that this is the first cooling—unless there was a cooling earlier in the context which has not been included here—since  "further cooled" implies additional cooling, not, "furthermore, they are cooled" or "further along in the process, they are cooled".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You've caught the good point here which was the reason of my questioning - unless there was any cooling beforehand - using the *"further cooled for.."* in the sentence looks irrelevant if the writer wanted to refer to the "additional cooling" by that word, but then you've also ended up with the same construal - *additional cooling*... In order to have the bricks cooled down additionally, wouldn't you need to chill it atleast a bit earlier ?

Comment: You could say, *Further, they are cooled...* Or more awkwardly "They are, further, cooled..."  A simple **then** would have sufficed.  "They are then cooled..."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  do you think that the usage presented in the passage is poorly formed regarding the cohesiveness with the context or something different meaning needs to be construed of the usage?

Comment: There are a couple of things in the passage which strike me as not quite idiomatic, although they are marginally grammatical; they are the kinds of slips that native speakers sometimes make when writing.  For example "bricks are dried ... before *baking them*..." instead of "before being baked".  And *further* when it could be simple *then*.  And "loaded in trucks, thus, preparing them" is wooden; "thus" is overkill; it could be simply "loaded onto trucks, to be delivered..."

Comment: "thus"actually appeared to be redundant for me too but I wouldn't even believe that the contradiction of *bricks are dried...before baking them* could be considered as mis-use. I always thought this kind of usage is simply for adding variety to the sentence. Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the context, we know that the "cooling" occurs after the "baking".

However in

> They are **further** cooled for 48-72 hours in the cooling chamber

"further" describes the cooling process meaning *additional cooling* and the additional time is implied through the context (things take time to cool down)

whereas

> They are cooled for **a further** 48-72 hours in the cooling chamber

describes the *additional* time of 48-72 hours.

Comment: Hi peter, so you mean that in order to avoid ambiguity the second choice seems more convenient? right?

Comment: Yes, "*further cooled*" emphasizes the *cooling*, "*for a further* 48-72 hours" emphasizes the added time, it could also be written as "*for an additional* 48-72 hours", just depends which you want to be more important.